# Update custom endpoint in Azure Service Fabric Cluster

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-virtual-network

How do I edit/update the custom endpoint in Azure Service Fabric Cluster after the cluster has been created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You need find your SF cluster load balancer. Modify the port of `Health probes` and `Load balancing rules`, you could access service in SF cluster on new port.

[image]

More information about this please refer to this [link:Open ports for a Service Fabric cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/create-load-balancer-rule).